# java.lang.SecurityException Permission Denial pool-1-thread-1

Tags: android

I'm having this problem when I try to launch an application.
Where I should start the debugging? What could be the problem? Thanks

```
01-05 15:16:31.921: E/AndroidRuntime(8308): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1
01-05 15:16:31.921: E/AndroidRuntime(8308): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.googlecode.pythonforandroid.PythonProvider from ProcessRecord{421cdcb0 8308:com.googlecode.android_scripting/u0a88} (pid=8308, uid=10088) that is not exported from uid 1000
01-05 15:16:31.921: E/AndroidRuntime(8308):     at com.googlecode.android_scripting.SingleThreadExecutor.afterExecute(SingleThreadExecutor.java:32)
01-05 15:16:31.921: E/AndroidRuntime(8308):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1120)
01-05 15:16:31.921: E/AndroidRuntime(8308):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-05 15:16:31.921: E/AndroidRuntime(8308):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: post coding of SingleThreadExecutor.java, error is at line no:32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I infer, you're trying to access provider **com.googlecode.pythonforandroid.PythonProvider**, but it looks like the exported flag has been set to false by them, hence you are not able to access it and getting Permission denial exception. 
Whenever in doubt, check Android docs: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#exported